# MissingMethodException when using NLog on Xamarin.Android

Tags: .net, xamarin.android, nlog

I am trying to use NLog in my Xamarin.Android project. When I call `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` it throws a `MissingMethodException`.

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'StringBuilder.AppendFormat' not found.
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger (NLog.LoggerCacheKey cacheKey) [0x0013a] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at NLog.LogFactory.GetLogger (System.String name) [0x00011] in <filename unknown>:0 
   at NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger () [0x0000a] in <filename unknown>:0
```

All I have done is add the NLog nuget packages (version 4.3.8) to my project and add the following line of code to my `Application` class:

```
private static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

I followed the same steps with a new blank Xamarin.Android application and got the same results. However, when I did the same thing with a new blank WPF application, it worked as expected so I'm thinking this is an issue specific to the Xamarin.Android platform.

Comment: That's strange as there is an appendFormat in Xamarin: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat/p/System.String/System.Object/ and https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat/p/System.String/System.Object[]/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ends up here with a similar issue, I was able to resolve this by simply updating Xamarin.

Comment: Could you post the Xamarin version before and after update?

Comment: having same issue... is there any chance you changed any other settings?

Comment: @chrispepper1989 Nope, all I did was update Xamarin to the latest version at the time. Unfortunately I don't know what version I was on before updating.